# center images in div with max width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making this site to display bike trips. Users can search for trips by entering their ID. When they push the search button, the trips will appear in the browser. The problem I have is that I want them centered and not floating to the left. This may seem like a simple problem but I tried several things and I ran out of options. Problem is in fact that the width of my div, containing all trips, is the same as the width of my page. This disables me to use automargins left and right. I want to display as many images possible in the width of my screen but when I leave out float:left, they only appear one above the other. Link of website: [Just type CW1A1 as GroupID and click search to see the trips](http://www.student.kuleuven.be/~r0449585/index_recr.html)

```
#tripimages p {
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:250px;
}

#tripimages {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You can get closer to what you are going for by using a percentage margin.. `#tripimages p { margin-left: 6% }` but it still won't be perfectly centered unless you make specific layouts for the screen size using media queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think as long as you have `float: left`, your elements are going to... wait for it... float left.

The best option I've come up with is get rid of the float and add `display: inline-block`.

Oh, and make sure you add `vertical-align:`<strike>middle</strike>`top;`... your last div was getting a bit out of line there.

Comment: Just to add, `float` won't be sufficient in some cases ( when image sizes will be unequal) . Please go ahead and try [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Thanks mate! That did the trick, but is there any way to have the last line of images vertical aligned beneath the ones above?

Comment: yw. I'm not sure I follow. Did you do the `vertical-align:top;` trick? Are they **not** aligning correctly?

Comment: I did add the vertical align and it worked to prevent the last line from screwing up. It's just that when there are, let's say, 4 images next to eachother but the last line only has 3, they get centered too while I want them to stay on the left (right under the first 3 images of the line above instead of between image 1 and 2,2 and 3,3 and 4)

Comment: Ohh, gotcha... yeah, you gotta go back to float: left; then, and try to give your parent (`#tripimages`) a specific width for each `@media` query (that is, if your page is responsive).

Comment: seems like I'll stick with the way it is

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display: inline-block;`

```
#tripimages p {
    display: inline-block
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    margin:10px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    padding-top:250px;
}
```